# Error: There are no form controls registered with this group yet. If you're using ngModel,you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout)

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am using template driven form and am trying to set the value of the form elements based on some object properties, however i face the following [image: Error] on doing so.
Also here is my code for the TD form and how i am trying to access it.

.html file:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onAddDevice(f)" #f="ngForm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" ngModel required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
          <label for="type">Type</label>
          <input type="text" id="type" class="form-control" name="type" ngModel required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
          <label for="platform">Platform</label>
          <input type="text" id="platform" class="form-control" name="platform" ngModel required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
          <label for="udid">UDID</label>
          <input type="text" id="udid" class="form-control" name="udid" ngModel required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Add</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Delete</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts file:

```
  @ViewChild('f') deviceForm: NgForm;
  @Output() deviceAdded = new EventEmitter<DeviceModel>();
  editedItemIndex: number;
  editedDevice: DeviceModel;

  constructor(private deviceService: DeviceService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) =>{
            this.id = +params['id'];
            this.editMode = params['id'] != null;
            if ( this.editMode) {
              this.editedItemIndex = params['id'];
              this.editedDevice = this.deviceService.getDevice(params['id']);
              console.log(this.editedDevice.frame);
              this.deviceForm.setValue({
                name: this.editedDevice.name,
                platform: this.editedDevice.platform,
                type: this.editedDevice.type,
                udid: this.editedDevice.frame
              });
            }
        }
      );
  }
```

The problem is because of calling the setValue method on the form.

Comment: it's not [(ngModel)] ?? see https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms

Comment: why should it be [(ngModel)] , im not using two way binding, on checking further i notice the set value works if i call it outside subscribe, so probably has to do something with the observable.

Comment: if is one way use [ngModel], or [value]

Comment: i think in form elements we can just specify using NgModel, however thats not the problem, the problem is calling the setValue() method in the subscribe under the ngOnInit

Comment: After checking the problem was with subscribe, which had a faulty implementation.

Comment: @SajidManzoor hi, I'm having the same issue, if you have found the solution would you post it please?

Answer (score 10):

As you are using template driven forms, the form controls will not be registered on init of the component.
As the error message suggests use the setTimeout(), wrap your setvalue() as below, it will fix the issue.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
       this.deviceForm.setValue({
        name: this.editedDevice.name,
        platform: this.editedDevice.platform,
        type: this.editedDevice.type,
        udid: this.editedDevice.frame
      });
    }, );
```

Hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same problem, and I solved it doing this (the code snippet below, uses your form controls):

```js
this.deviceForm.form.patchValue({
    name: this.editedDevice.name,
    platform: this.editedDevice.platform,
    type: this.editedDevice.type,
    udid: this.editedDevice.frame
});
```

Comment: worked for me and IHMO this is really better than calling `setTimeout` which trigger a new life-cycle detection run.

Comment: The settimeout way worked for me the first time but as soon as I made a few more changes to the code I started getting the same error. This other solution worked just fine and, as it has already been mentioned just above this comment, it is technically much better. Thanks!

Comment: patchValue works well, since setValue requires all the fields to be present and to exactly match, but patchValue accepts any number of matching fields - it picks only the matching. Since we are still in ngOnInit, the form object will work well with patchValue since it will accept any changes passed.

Comment: patchValue differ from setValue that patcValue just fails silently

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found is to assign the subscribe to a subscription and use OnDestroy to unsubscribe.

```
export class ShoppingEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('f') form: NgForm;
  subscription :Subscription;
  id: number;
  editMode: boolean = false;

  constructor(private slService: ShoppingListService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.slService.ingredientSelected.subscribe(
      (index: number) => {                        
        let ingredient = this.slService.getIngredient(index);
        this.form.setValue({
          name: ingredient.name,
          amount: ingredient.amount
        });        
        this.id = index;
        this.editMode = true;
      }
    )
  }

 ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like:

```
if(this.deviceForm.controls['name']){
        this.deviceForm.setValue({
            name: this.editedDevice.name,
            platform: this.editedDevice.platform,
            type: this.editedDevice.type,
            udid: this.editedDevice.frame
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because in my form group I had a FormArray instead of a FormControl.
Try checking your form group.